# Polymer Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, polymer

There are examples of using Google Maps in polymer for example

```
<google-map latitude="37.77493" longitude="-122.41942" fitToMarkers>
  <google-map-marker latitude="37.779" longitude="-122.3892"
      draggable="true" title="Go Giants!"></google-map-marker>
  <google-map-marker latitude="37.777" longitude="-122.38911"></google-map-marker>
</google-map>
```

From this how do you interact/interface with the map for example move the center or use other API functions?
Using `var mapElement = document.querySelector('google-map');` in the script section of the standard Polymer format just comes back undefined.
Thanks
Sean

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer it makes sense now I know since the document is just the Body not the contents of the Template.

```
var mapElement = this.shadowRoot.getElementById('google_map');
```

Hopefully I can do anything I need with mapElement.